# Postfix increase recepients limit

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I am using Postfix to send mass mails to our customers. But at a time I can only mail to  1000 recepients (mail IDs in Bcc). If I increase the count it says too many recepients.

How can I increase the recepients limit?

Comment: Why not just send 1k at a time?

Answer (score 4):

As described  [in the postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_limit) the parameter is smtpd_recipient_limit.

So if you want 2000 as a new limit, the following will do it:

```
# postconf -e smtpd_recipient_limit=2000
```